# CSV/Excel to JSON API for prototyping

Tags: javascript, sql, json, csv, prototyping

I have a CSV file and I want to use it in different visualization frameworks (d3, Google Charts etc). Is there a platform that allows me to quickly:

1. Upload the CSV file
2. Access the content of the file as JSON
3. Extra points if I could query the JSON (SQL style)
4. Extra points if I could upload more than one CSV file and use query joins to link the two together

I've tried to use Google Spreadsheets and Google Visualization API Query Language. The issue is that when you get the JSON from Spreadsheets, you get it in a spreadsheet format (as in, every cell gets one item, rather than the initial format of the CSV file).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library, where you can

a) Upload CSV file.

```
 alasql('SELECT * FROM CSV("cities.csv")', [], function(cities){
     console.log("Cities:", cities);
 });
```

b) Access the content of the file as JSON:

```
 alasql('SELECT * FROM CSV("mydata.csv",{headers:true})', [], function(mydata){
     console.log("First city name:", mydata[0].City);
 });
```

c) Query the JSON (SQL style)

```
alasql('SELECT * FROM CSV("mydata.csv",{headers:true}) WHERE Population > 100000',
  [], function(mydata){
      console.log("Big cities:", mydata);
});
```

d) Upload more than one CSV file and use query joins to link the two together

```
alasql('SELECT cities.*  FROM CSV("cities.csv",{headers:true}) AS cities \
   JOIN CSV("countires.csv",{headers:true}) AS countries \
   ON cities.country = countries.country \
   WHERE countries.continent = "Afrika"',
   [], function(res){
      console.log("African cities: ",res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get a csv from the Google Spreadsheet using the visualization API.

Try this, the csv variable will be set to the sheet using the dataTableToCsv() helper function. You can use other convenience functions to include the column heads if you need them. [See the Visualization/Chart docs for more.](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews)

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
        "modules":[{
        "name":"visualization",
        "version":"1"
        }]
      }'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ&pub=1');

    // Apply query language statement.
    query.setQuery('SELECT *');

    // Send the query with a callback function.
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();

 var csv = google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(data);
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="visualization" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's also possible to directly download a csv from a spreadsheet by setting the query at the end of the url. You'll need a service to handle the cross-domain request, though, if you want to submit a call.